# Get username from selection in ClientPeoplePicker and store it in a list item

Tags: user-profile, people-picker

I have a web control with a ClientPeoplePicker on it.

**[image: The ClientPeoplePicker]**

```
<tr>
    <td class="auto-style1">User Name<span class="ms-error">*</span></td>
    <td>
        <Sharepoint:ClientPeoplePicker
                    Required="true"
                    ValidationEnabled="true"
                    ID="peoplePicker"
                    runat="server"
                    InitialHelpText="Please, insert a valid User!"
                    VisibleSuggestions="3"
                    Rows="1"
                    AllowMultipleEntities="false"
                    CssClass="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" />
     </td>
</tr>
```

I need to fetch the name of the selected user in the control to store it in a text field of a list item I am creating (in the above example, I would need to get the "Georgi Krystev" string). So far my code looks like that:

```
itemAdd["FullName"] = Convert.ToString(txtEmpFName.Text);
itemAdd["UserName"] = Convert.ToString(peoplePicker); // This don't work, how should I replace it?
itemAdd["EGN"] = Convert.ToInt64(txtEmpEGN.Text);

itemAdd.Update();

oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

This however is not recovering the information I need. Can anyone point out what I am missing to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Can you please stop editing your question to give it new meaning after you have received answers? For new problems you should ask new questions.

Comment: OKAY, SORRY FOR THIS :(

Comment: Delete the post, I create new..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the display name of the user, then the following snippet should be enough:

```
PickerEntity picker = (PickerEntity)peoplePicker.ResolvedEntities[0];
SPUser userInstance = oSPWeb.EnsureUser(picker.Key);
itemAdd["UserName"] = userInstance.Name;
```

Note: the code above assumes there is at least one resolved entity available from the picker. You will have to add custom logic to manage multiple selected users or no user selected at all as needed.

Comment: I need to add one User ! :)

Comment: and field is requred :)

Comment: THIS IS WORK!!!